# Getting error while data migration in elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to migrate data from sandbox(Azure) to staging(AWS), but getting the error

I tried the elasticdump command with --bulk=true and --maxSockets=5 but still same issue

elasticdump --input=/home/upasana/dumpdata/index.json --output=https://username:password@endpoint:port/index --type=mapping --headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}' --maxSockets=5

elasticdump --input=/home/upasana/dumpdata/index.json --output=https://username:password@endpoint:port/index --type=mapping --headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}' --bulk=true

I am passing username and password in command so its not related to authentication

Error:
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
Wed, 14 Jun 2023 05:25:24 GMT | got 1 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Wed, 14 Jun 2023 05:25:25 GMT | Error Emitted => {"ok":false,"message":"Forbidden"}

Wed, 14 Jun 2023 05:25:25 GMT | Error Emitted => {"ok":false,"message":"Forbidden"}

Wed, 14 Jun 2023 05:25:25 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Wed, 14 Jun 2023 05:25:25 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => FORBIDDEN: {"ok":false,"message":"Forbidden"}

Comment: Can you run the same commands with `--debug` so we can see the executed commands?

Comment: Yes, I tried with --debug, but giving same response

Is it possible to migrate data from Azure to AWS, in case if configuration issue is there?

Also, I created new Azure deployment and tried to move the data, its working if provider is same

Comment: In the second command you should probably have `--type=data` instead of `--type=mapping`. With the former, it's working fine for me from local file to Elastic Cloud. What version of elasticdump and ES are you using?